# When I deploy an angular 5 app on firebase the api's where blocked

Tags: angular

The Error is:-
Mixed Content: The page at 'https:/app/home' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/home'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

In case of https(SSL) website, every request should be with https. The reverse is not true, meaning you could have some https request even when your website is running with http.

1. Try running the first page https:/app/home without https as http:/app/home
2. Setup an SSL server for your http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/home URL. You could follow this URL for setting it up on your machine (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec)

For more info read this article https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/what-is-mixed-content